# Any software/ hardware clients that support RDP 8.0 with RemoteFX?

Tags: rdp, rds, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop

As the title suggests are there any software and/ or hardware clients available **now** that support Microsoft RDP version 8.0 with RemoteFX? The only one I've read about is MS RDP client in Windows 8.

**UPDATE:** I contacted Dell Wyse and at the moment the only support for RDP 8 and enhanced RemoteFX is in Windows 8 and Server 2012. Apparently, MS have not decided when to release an updated RDP client for Windows 7 and that delays third-party support for RDP 8.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if they support RDP 8.0, yet, but your best bet might be [iTap Mobile](http://itap-mobile.com/) as they currently support RemoteFX on iPad/iPhone as well as Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

HP released a RDP 8 add-on for their WES7 based thin clients.

[HP WES7 Add-On (Microsoft RDP 8)](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=12454&prodSeriesId=4282707&prodNameId=4282708&swEnvOID=4089&swLang=13&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=vc-112814-1)

HARDWARE PRODUCT MODEL(S) (WES7 versions only):

- HP t510 Flexible Thin Client
- HP t5570e Thin Client
- HP t5740e Thin Client
- HP t610 Flexible Thin Client
- HP t610 PLUS Flexible Thin Client

OPERATING SYSTEM(S):

- Microsoft Windows Embedded Standard 7E 32-Bit
- Microsoft Windows Embedded Standard 7P 32-Bit

PREREQUISITES: 
- For Microsoft Windows Embedded Standard 7E, image version 6.1.7601.252 (or later) is required.

Answer (score 0):

MS has released [an update for RDP8 and remoteFX8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2012/10/23/rdp-8-0-update-for-windows-7-sp1-released-to-web.aspx). See [KB2592687](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2592687) for installation instructions.